# Pc gets stuttering when another application opens

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, 23.04

I seem to have a problem that every time I open app, doesn't matter which almost all functionality gets stuttering or just frozen
and I mean everything from sound (friends over discord sounds stuttering) to youtube videos and even moving windows around.
I happends worst when opening Steam seems to be slow to open, but occur on everything even opening Dolphin

I use Kubuntu 23.04 (also happend with 22.04) with Nvidia driver 535
My specs are
I5-13400F (should calrify I also dont notice any real hard load on the cpu)
RTX 3070 8GB (maybe due to nvidia drivers being shit? idrk)
32g ram 3200
nvme ssd samsung 770

Do any one know anything or can help me?

Comment: You can open the system monitor to view resource usage.